# Ti Nspire: Convert solve(...) output to a callable Function

Tags: ti-basic, ti-nspire

in order to calculate the inverse function of f(x) I defined following function:

```
inv(fx):=exp▶list(solve(fx=y,x),x)
```

which output is:

```
inv(x^(2))           {piecewise(−√(y),y≥0),piecewise(√(y),y≥0)}
```

So that part works already, but how can I use this result as a callable function i(y)?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Outside of your program, you can turn the result into function `i(y)` with:

```
i(y):=piecewise(-√(y),y≥0,√(y),y≥0)
```

I do not have a CAS, so your results may differ, but, because the function can only return one value, it would only return (and display in the graph) the first value, in this case, `-√(y)`.  If you want to display on the graph or get the values of both, you would be better off creating two separate functions (`-√(y)`, and `√(y)`).  Hope this helps you "use the result as a callable function."